# iOS html view different from other views. Is there a reason or is it just vertical sizing?

Tags: html, ios, css

This is a mobile-only view so it's not applicable in a desktop browser. Here's the site: https://jkoller3.github.io The buttons rendered fine on my Android. Is this a common issue? Is there something about the iOS version of these browsers that's causing it to do this? And is there something I can do to resolve this?

I don't have any vertically oriented media queries... is that what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what specifically on your page is causing you issues, but try adding the following CSS to the elements causing you trouble:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

I know that's helped me as iOS tends to style things in it's own way and that removes the default styling.

Answer (score 0):

I just set the specific properties that are being overridden by the browser to !important.